preserve-3d doesnt seem to work in firefox
I´m currently trying to do a coinflip like animation with plain css and html.
In chrome everything works fine but in firefox it doesnt show one of the images when rotating the coin.
This is the css for the animation, which works fine.
.coinflip-playerOne {
  -webkit-animation: flipHeads 3.5s ease-out forwards;
  -moz-animation: flipHeads 3.5s ease-out forwards;
  -o-animation: flipHeads 3.5s ease-out forwards;
  animation: flipHeads 3.5s ease-out forwards;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

.coinflip-playerTwo {
  -webkit-animation: flipTails 3.5s ease-out forwards;
  -moz-animation: flipTails 3.5s ease-out forwards;
  -o-animation: flipTails 3.5s ease-out forwards;
  animation: flipTails 3.5s ease-out forwards;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@keyframes flipHeads {
  0% {
    transform: none;
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1.5) rotateY(1080deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(0.9) rotateY(1980deg);
  }
}

@keyframes flipTails {
  0% {
    transform: none;
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1.5) rotateY(1080deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(0.9) rotateY(2160deg);
  }
}

This is the html part for the coin. (As you can see I use tailwind here)
<div
          className={
            "w-36 h-36 cursor-pointer relative rounded-full border-4 border-yellow-200" +
            (result === 1 ? " coinflip-playerOne" : "") +
            (result === 2 ? " coinflip-playerTwo" : "")
          }
          style={{ transformStyle: "preserve-3d" }}
        >
          <div className="absolute w-full h-full">
            <img
              src={"https://crafatar.com/avatars/" + playerOne + "?size=128"}
              className="w-full rounded-full"
              style={{ transform: "rotateY(180deg)" }}
            ></img>
          </div>
          <div
            className="absolute w-full h-ful"
            style={{ backfaceVisibility: "hidden" }}
          >
            <img
              src={"https://crafatar.com/avatars/" + playerTwo + "?size=128"}
              className="w-full rounded-full"
            ></img>
          </div>
        </div>

Here you can see a gif on how it looks on chrome or firefox.


Does this answer your question? How to preserve-3d using css - firefox issue

@DarkBee I tried adding the <img
src={"https://crafatar.com/avatars/" + playerTwo + "?size=128"}
className="w-full rounded-full"
style={{ transform: "rotateY(0deg)" }}
>
to the second image which starts on top. I still cant see the second image though

I'm not sure on how to apply it to your template (engine) though, but maybe someone else can shed a light

The css property is added to the image. I just checked it in the web inspector. Might there be another piece of css missing? Like perspective?

You can always go upvote the answer in the linked question to express your thanks :)
